# Is there a way to retrieve the date of the first post of an Instragram account?

Tags: csv, web-scraping, instagram

I am trying to export a CSV file that will show me the Instagram username along with the date of their first post in order to have an idea of when the account was created. I cannot find coding anywhere to solve this. There has to be a way.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to retrieve the required data using the Instagram API.

Link to API documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api

Once you fetch the required data, you can store and download in csv format.

Hope this helps.